# Redirecting 2 or more domains to same hosting server

Tags: web-hosting, dns, multiple-domains

I have domains A.com, A.co.in and A.in Purchased from site X.

I have a hosting space/account purchased from site Y, which has provided me with 2 DNS entries that is to be replaced in the account at the site from where I purchase the domains.

I have successfully changed the DNS entries of A.com to these 2 DNS entries and I am able to see my index.html page when I hit A.com.

#### Problem

On similar lines, I have changed the DNS entries to the same entries for A.co.in and A.in, but on hitting those sites in browser gives me no response and browser specific page of 'Site not found' is been seen.

Please let me know, how to set this, so that when I hit any of the domain, the web-site is rendered from the hosting server? What am I doing wrong here?

#### Note

1. It has been more than 3 days after changing the DNS entries, so I don't think so this is a problem of DNS propagation, which I heard from some people.
2. Please provide some detail explanation, as I am very very new to this. This is my first hosting ;)

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Right after you change your domain DNS, you should go into your hosting service and "park" domain. Simply add its name to the server you are using ( provided DNS must point to that server ). If you did that, well nothing else than wait :) if this doesn't help, try contacting your domain provider, sometimes they don't accept DNS addresses from unknown places.

Comment: +1 the additional domains need to be _parked_ on your hosting account. The hosting account needs to be told to accept requests from these other domains, otherwise the requests will not be accepted, which appears to be what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Quite odd.. My suggesstion is take a look at zoneedit.com, then you can point your domain to zoneedit first. Go to DNS setting, plesae create the DNS record same as the DNS setting on your control panel now. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the A.co.in and A.in to the A.com record/IP. There are primarily two types of DNS records you'll need to set to get it all set up right, a CNAME and an A record.

```
*.A.co.in     CNAME    A.com.
A.co.in       A        IP of A.com

*.A.in        CNAME    A.com.
A.in          A        IP of A.com
```

You may want to change the *.A.co.in to www.A.co.in if you're using other subdomains for other things, but it sounds like *. would work fine for you and would cover all possibilities. That handles the www., etc. On the A.co.in that is an A record you give it the same IP that you have A.com set up to.

That's all the DNS settings. You'll have to set up the web server to receive A.in and A.co.in as an alias for A.com, in apache this is a ServerAlias. That way when it's received at the right IP the web server will know it's not a random other site being requested, but that these are all alias for the same thing.